# How can I express that X is as big/small/fast/... as Y?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, comparative-constructions, comparison

I would like to know how to express that something is equal in some aspect to another thing (or person, if that makes a difference), as you would express in English by saying:

X is as (adjective) as Y

for example: This car is as fast as that car.

It would also be interesting for me to learn how to say:

"is not as (adjective) as"
"is nearly as (adj) as"
"can/might/will be as (adj) as"
"want to be as (adj) as"

Comment: Did you try consulting a dictionary? http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=nearly+as http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=as
http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=not+as

Answer (score 8):

In addition to `くらい／ぐらい` as @rintuan mentioned, `ほど` (meaning "extent" or "limit") is your friend:

> #### X is not as (adjective) as Y　→　ほど〜ない
>
> - あの少年はお兄さん**ほど**背が**高くない**　→　That boy is not as tall as his older brother.
> - 生物学は物理学**ほど**面白く**ない**　→　Biology is not as interesting as physics.
>
> #### Other comparisons: "to the extent of 〜"
>
> - 今日はセーターを着るほど寒い　→　Today is cold enough to (need to) wear a sweater; "Today is cold to the extent of wearing a sweater"

Some other alternatives:

> #### Two things being nearly equal in some aspect
>
> - この車とあの車と、速さはだいたい同じ　→　This car is about as fast as that car; "As for this car and that car, their speeds are about the same"
> - ねこくらいの大きさのネズミ　→　A rat (about) as big as a cat

Answer (score 6):

### Exactly what you're looking for...

One phrase which I believe will help you is 「～と同【おな】じくらい～」. This literally means "to the same degree as" and seems like it will fit what you're asking for. Some examples:

> - 耳【みみ】が顔【かお】と同じくらい大きい。 His ears are as big as his face.
> - モデルと同じくらいかわいい。 She is as cute as a model.

This form will with with i-adjectives, but with na-adjectives, you'll need to use に, e.g.:

> - ちっちゃい魚【さかな】もおっきい魚と同じくらいに[上手]{じょうず}に泳【およ】ぐよ。 Small fish swim just as well as big fish.

### ...And a [better?] alternative

Of course, you might also consider using 「～のように～」. It doesn't capture *exactly* the same nuance, but I think it does well enough. It also has the benefit of sounding much more natural in many scenarios. For example:

> - 輝【かがや】く瞳【ひとみ】は星【ほし】のようにきれい。 Your shining eyes are beautiful like the stars.

### Extending the meaning

Both of these phrases are equally versatile when you want to extend their meanings. You mentioned "not as", "can/might/will be as", and "want to be as"... all of these are possible by doing what you'd normally do in Japanese to say these things.

> - モデルと同じくらいかわいくなりたい。 I want to be as cute as a model. [Note: It's true! I do!]
> - 耳【みみ】が顔【かお】と同じくらい大きくなるだろう。 His eyes will probably be as big as his face.
> - 人【ひと】は魚と同じくらいに[上手]{じょうず}に泳【およ】げないよ。 A person can't swim as well as a fish.

And just in case you really want your girlfriend to break up with you:

> - 瞳【ひとみ】は星【ほし】のようにきれいじゃない。 Your eyes are not beautiful like the stars.

<sub>Note: basis for example sentences sourced from various Japanese-language websites.</sub>